# PushPlugin PhoneGap doesn't work on iOS

Tags: android, ios, cordova, apple-push-notifications

I installed and configured PushPlugin on Cordova: https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.

On Android everything is working:

- Cordova PushNOtification Plugin Demo
- Deviceready event received
- registering android
- success: ok
- EVENT -> RECEIVED:registred -> token . . .

On iOS I just got this (without errors):

- Cordova PushNOtification Plugin Demo
- Deviceready event received
- registering iOS

As if this following function isn't called and then I don't get the token:

```
function tokenHandler (result) {
// Your iOS push server needs to know the token before it can push to this device
// here is where you might want to send it the token for later use.
alert('device token = ' + result);
}
```

Maybe I should implement somewhere the apple push notification authorization ?

Thanks

Comment: you make provisioning profile and certificate which includes APNS from apple developer account?

Comment: yes, and I just put it into xcode right ?